# Is the uniform distribution over a convex set log convex or log concave?

Tags: probability-distributions, convex-analysis

I read in Boyd's text that over convex $C$ such a distribution:

$$f(x) = {1\over a} I_C(x)$$

for $I$ the indicator function for $C$ and $a$ the measure of $C$. And that taking $\log 0 = -\infty$ we have that $\log f$ is $-\log a$ for $x \in C$ and $-\infty$ otherwise. Then the text asserts that because this is concave the distribution is log concave. But isn't $-\log x$ a convex function? (Second derivative is $1/x^2$ which is always positive). I keep thinking it should be log convex, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function $g$ is concave if, for every $x$ and $y$ and every $t$ in $(0,1)$,
$$
g(tx+(1-t)y)\geqslant tg(x)+(1-t)g(y)\qquad\qquad (\ast)
$$ 
If $g=\log f$ for your function $f$, two cases arise:

- Either $x$ and $y$ are in $C$, then $tx+(1-t)y$ is in $C$ as well because $C$ is convex, hence $g(x)=g(y)=g(tx+(1-t)y)=-\log a$ and $(\ast)$ holds.
- Or, $x$ or $y$ is not in $C$, then $g(x)=-\infty$ or $g(y)=-\infty$ hence the RHS of $(\ast)$ is $-\infty$ and $(\ast)$ holds.

Hence $g=\log f$ is concave and $f$ is log-concave.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 1):

The function $\log f(x)$ should be concave with respect to $x$, not with respect to $a$. When $x\in C$, your distribution function is constant, and hence all derivatives are zero here.

Comment: ohhhhhhhhhhhh good point...

Answer (score -1):

Consider $- \log f$: This is finite on a convex set and $+\infty$ on the complement, hence the epigraph is convex. Hence $- \log f$ is convex, it follows that $\log f$ is concave.

Comment: Why the down vote?